# Relative links to a specific file in Jekyll [myfile](blah.md) does not work (also does not work on gh-pages)

Tags: github, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I have the problem with relative links to a specific file not working at all both on gh-pages and on jekyll locally.  Here is my setup->

i have a directory like this:

```
/
README.md
README.ja.md
```

and I do a link like `[english](README.md)` and `[japanese](README.ja.md)` both links work on github.com (where they render the README below the code directory structure), but DO NOT work on gh-pages.  I tested jekyll locally and it also **DOES NOT** work.  If I move the directory structure around like

```
/
README.md
japanese/
..README.md
```

this will work... the link has to change to .`[japanese](./japanese/)`

I can also make this work on the original directory structure at the top if I do links like this->
`[japanese](README.ja) (no more .md)`

but then it will NOT work on the normal github.com b/c its not a valid link (since the file README.ja does not exist)

I have tried multiple attempts on jekyll locally, the only one that seems to work is removing the .md, but then it won't work on github

here is my _config file

```
theme: jekyll-theme-dinky
exclude:
  - "*.yml"
  - "*.yaml"
plugins:
  - jekyll-relative-links
relative_links:
  enabled: true
  collections: true
```

I want it to actually render versus just load the un-rendered website :( https://ipvsean.github.io/workshops/exercises/ansible_rhel/1.2-adhoc/japanREADME.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed with this commit https://github.com/IPvSean/workshops/commit/17f52069a9f7ae5582b1202092dc75e140400058

basically this was original

```
[![japan](../../../images/japan.png) 日本語](README.ja).
```

and this is what will work

```
![japan](../../../images/japan.png) [日本語](README.ja).
```

trying to do something fancy like linking the image as well as the text Japanese made the relative link in Jekyll fail, as soon as I just placed the image next to it, it will work.  This made me pull my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `README.ja.md` to `README_ja.md`? And having them both at the root directory.

Comment: Yes the file name doesn’t matter :( I can link to any file within the same directory